# Classification tasks where machines achieve significantly higher accuracy than humans

Tags: classification, references

Spam filtering is an example of classification task where machines achieve approximately similar accuracy as humans. On the other hand, [Asirra](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/74609/CCS2007.pdf) (recognizing cats and dogs in images) is an example where humans significantly outperform machines.

Are there any examples of classification tasks where machines achieve significantly higher accuracy than humans?

Comment: I suspect that you'll find lots of examples when the data is too high-dimensional to visualize and too abstract to "read".  Gene expression studies, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, for example, skin cancer diagnosis:

ROC AUC: 0.86 vs. 0.79, p < 0.01

[Source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29846502)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to narrow down your definition of "classification task" for the question to make sense. If I use a broad definition, many mathematical problems can be formulated as classification tasks where computers achieve 100% accuracy while humans will find the problem almost impossible. E.g. is this number prime (for large numbers)?, does this (large) graph have a [Hamiltonian path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path), etc.